# What is the reason of this weird area subtraction issue?

Tags: java, collision-detection, area

While I was coding an algorithm of collision detection I have come up at this problem. It is something weird which is beyond my understanding.

**The problem here is** that if in my algorithm, presented in function `tryMove()`, I add `potentialArea` to `moveLineArea` and I am doing detection of change in the `spaceTestArea` (which is created from the `moveLineArea`) after subtracting areas taken by all units, I have a collision with a unit that is not even close `x=280,y=120`, where moving unit is at `x=1880,y=120`, and it is moving to `x=1914,y=126`.

**I would like to know** what might be the reason of this issue and what to do in order to avoid it in future.

I must say I have a temporary solution (`tryMove2()`) but please do not let it influence your thinking, i.e. I do not like this solution and I strongly believe that the first solution (`tryMove()`) should work and it must be me who forgot about something.

Please see below the code presenting the problem.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Test showing some unexpected and weird behaviour of area subtraction.
 * @author Konrad Borowiecki
 */
public class TestTryMove {
    private static final List<Point> unitCenterPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    static{
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1720, 120));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1880, 120));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1800, 200));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1720, 280));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1880, 280));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 120));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 120));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(200, 200));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 280));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 280));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 1720));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 1720));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(200, 1800));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 1880));
        unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 1880));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] xpointsOK = new int[]{1876, 1884, 1918, 1910};//for Move OK
        int[] ypointsOK = new int[]{139, 101, 108, 146};//for Move OK
        Polygon lineOK = new Polygon(xpointsOK, ypointsOK, xpointsOK.length);

        int[] xpointsFAIL = new int[]{1877, 1883, 1917, 1911};//for problem no move
        int[] ypointsFAIL = new int[]{139, 101, 107, 145};//for problem no move
        Polygon lineFAIL = new Polygon(xpointsFAIL, ypointsFAIL, xpointsFAIL.length);

        Point endPointCPOK = new Point(1914, 127);//Move OK
        Point endPointCPFAIL = new Point(1914, 126);//problem no move
        //where in both cases it should be move OK              
        System.out.println("******TEST for method tryMove()******");            
        System.out.println("TEST 1: this will FAIL");
        System.out.println("Result="+tryMove(endPointCPFAIL, lineFAIL)); 
        System.out.println("\nTEST 2: this will be OK");
        System.out.println("Result="+tryMove(endPointCPOK, lineOK));


        System.out.println("******TEST for method tryMove2()******");   
        System.out.println("TEST 1: this will be OK");
        System.out.println("Result="+tryMove2(endPointCPFAIL, lineFAIL)); 
        System.out.println("\nTEST 2: this will be OK");
        System.out.println("Result="+tryMove2(endPointCPOK, lineOK));
    }
    /**
     * Tests if a unit represented by point of index 1 in the list of 
     * unitCenterPoints (i.e. [1880, 120]) can make a move to the given endPointCP.
     * (Please notice we are ignoring this unit in the algorithm 
     * i.e. if(i != movingUnitIndexInTheArray)).
     * @param endPointCP the point where the unit moves to.
     * @param line the line of the move of the thickness equal to units width (mod=40), 
     * drawn between the current unit's center point and the endPointCP, 
     * represented as a polygon object.
     * @return true if move possible; false otherwise. 
     */
    private static boolean tryMove(Point endPointCP, Polygon line){
        Area potentialArea = getArea(endPointCP);
        Area moveLineArea = new Area(line);
        moveLineArea.add(potentialArea);
        //this area is used for testing if nothing stays on the way of the move
        Area spaceTestArea = new Area(moveLineArea);
        //the index of the unit making the move in the unitCenterPoints list
        int movingUnitIndexInTheArray = 1;
        //we are subtracting from spaceTestArea all areas of units
        for(int i = 0; i < unitCenterPoints.size(); i++)
            if(i != movingUnitIndexInTheArray) {
                Point p = unitCenterPoints.get(i);
                Area uArea = getArea(p);
                spaceTestArea.subtract(uArea);
                //we have intersection then return false, we cannot make this move  
                if(spaceTestArea.isEmpty() || !spaceTestArea.equals(moveLineArea)) {
                    System.out.println("No move --- a unit is on the way. "
                            + "Conflicting point is="+p +"; for i="+i);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        System.out.println("Move OK.");
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean tryMove2(Point endPointCP, Polygon line){
        Area potentialArea = getArea(endPointCP);
        Area moveLineArea = new Area(line);
        //test if unit can move to the new position
        Area potentialTestArea = new Area(potentialArea);
        //this area is used for testing if nothing stays on the way of the move
        Area spaceTestArea = new Area(moveLineArea);
        //the index of the unit making the move in the unitCenterPoints list
        int movingUnitIndexInTheArray = 1;
        //we are subtracting from spaceTestArea all areas of units
        for(int i = 0; i < unitCenterPoints.size(); i++)
            if(i != movingUnitIndexInTheArray) {
                Point p = unitCenterPoints.get(i);
                Area uArea = getArea(p);
                spaceTestArea.subtract(uArea);
                potentialTestArea.subtract(uArea);
                //we have intersection then return false, we cannot make this move  
                if(spaceTestArea.isEmpty() || !spaceTestArea.equals(moveLineArea)
                        || potentialTestArea.isEmpty() || !potentialTestArea.equals(potentialArea)) {
                    System.out.println("No move --- a unit is on the way. "
                            + "Conflicting point is="+p +"; for i="+i);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        System.out.println("Move OK.");
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the area taken by a unit given the unit's center point.
     * @param p the center point of a unit.
     * @return circle area.
     */ 
    private static Area getArea(Point p) {
        int mod = 40;//this is width and height of a unit
        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.x - mod / 2, p.y - mod / 2, mod, mod);
        return new Area(circle);
    }
}
```

And this is the output it is producing:

```
******TEST for method tryMove()******
TEST 1: this will FAIL
No move --- a unit is on the way. Conflicting point is=java.awt.Point[x=280,y=120]; for i=6; where moving unit point is=java.awt.Point[x=1880,y=120]; the unit is moving to=java.awt.Point[x=1914,y=126]
Result=false

TEST 2: this will be OK
Move OK.
Result=true
******TEST for method tryMove2()******
TEST 1: this will be OK
Move OK.
Result=true

TEST 2: this will be OK
Move OK.
Result=true
```

In order for you to see the problem better I have two images presenting it for two endPoints, first `1914, 126` when the method fails, and second `1914, 127` when it is OK.

[image: Here we have the problem.]

[image: Here is all OK.]

If more description is needed I will answer ASAP. Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT1:**
As suggested by @trashgod I did tried and implemented a solution which uses `intersect()` method. I do not like that for every test you must create a new object. Can you suggest some optimization for this algorithm.

```
private static boolean tryMove3(Point endPointCP, Polygon line){
    Area potentialArea = getArea(endPointCP);
    Area moveLineArea = new Area(line);
    moveLineArea.add(potentialArea);
    //this area is used for testing if nothing stays on the way of the move
    //the index of the unit making the move in the unitCenterPoints list
    int movingUnitIndexInTheArray = 1;
    //we are subtracting from spaceTestArea all areas of units
    for(int i = 0; i < unitCenterPoints.size(); i++)
        if(i != movingUnitIndexInTheArray) {
            Point p = unitCenterPoints.get(i);
            Area uArea = getArea(p);
            Area spaceTestArea = new Area(moveLineArea);
            spaceTestArea.intersect(uArea);
            //we have intersection then return false, we cannot make this move  
            if(!spaceTestArea.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No move --- a unit is on the way. "
                        + "Conflicting point is="+p +"; for i="+i
                        + "; where moving unit point is="
                        +unitCenterPoints.get(movingUnitIndexInTheArray)
                        +"; the unit is moving to="+endPointCP
                        +"; spaceTestArea.isEmpty()="+spaceTestArea.isEmpty());
                return false;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Move OK.");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running afoul of one of the ways [`java.awt.geom.Area`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) can become empty. If it helps, I took a picture, below. Alternatively, could you use `createTransformedShape()` and `contains()`?

Addendum: `tryMove3()` appears correct. If it really profiles worse, I see several possibilities:

- [Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) any static `Area`, perhaps those associated with each center point.
- Do a rough vicinity check based on `getBounds()` or a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) and skip remote pairs.

[image]

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.add(new JPanel(){

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.scale(10, 10);
        g2d.translate(-1875, -100);
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.draw(lineOK);
        g2d.setColor(Color.green.darker());
        g2d.drawRect(endPointCPOK.x, endPointCPOK.y, 1, 1);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.draw(lineFAIL);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red.darker());
        g2d.drawRect(endPointCPFAIL.x, endPointCPFAIL.y, 1, 1);
    }
});
f.pack();
f.setSize(450, 500);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Nice work 1+. I'm still unsure of and am trying to figure out this whole mess.

Comment: Thanks guys @trashgod @Hovercraft Full Of Eels +1 for the interesting answers. Though I must say I cannot use `contains()` as I care about any intersection even the smallest. Also I want my algorithm to not care about the actual shape and be accurate thus I must stick to Areas.

Comment: I was thinking that it might have something to do with what you are saying though I do not see why? I know that the areas are closed so this is not the issue. Maybe it has something to do with this: `A self-intersecting Shape may be split into two (or more) sub-paths each enclosing one of the non-intersecting portions of the original path.` - taken from the Area documentation. Though I must admit it is not clear to me.

Comment: @Boro: I don't see any empty areas or self-intersection; I think my guess was wrong. After looking at how `equals()` is implemented, the observation of @Hovercraft seems more likely to point the way.

Comment: @trashgod but doesn't it becomes self-intersect when you add the circle at the end of the polygon - cause that is effectively what I do, i.e. add the circle at the end of this 'thick line'/polygon?  @Hovercraft Full Of Eels so you guys think it is worth to give it a go at implementing your own `equlas()`, maybe something using path iterator? Did you guys see anything like this done by others?

Comment: @Boro: I suspect I don't really understand the goal. I'd have thought collision detection would use `intersect()` and `isEmpty()`.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for the suggestion. I remember trying this already and I know now why I went for a solution using `subtract()` method. The reason was that the subtract one doesn't require object creation for every test. Can you or @Hovercraft Full Of Eels please check out my EDIT1, the code is compatible with the rest? Can you suggest some optimization? BTW: I am still interested with the reason for the subtraction not working, it smells of bug to me.

Comment: Thanks @trashod I am accepting your answer as it was the most useful for me. Using your suggestion I have also extended my code with bounds contains & intersects as the first check. Thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels for you time. I have one more question for you guys, i.e. What else I can do with this issue? I think it is not mathematically correct thus I consider it to be a bug thus I am thinking of reporting it, should I and where is the best place to do this?

Comment: @Boro: My best guess is that this is a form of aliasing. Areas have floating point coordinates, while center points have integral coordinates. I'm not quite sure it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the 6th subtraction is changing the geometry of spaceTestArea so that it is not equal to moveLineArea and this may be seen visually by exlusiveOr'ing the two.  The Area API states only that equals tests if the two geometries are equal but unfortunately doesn't go into further detail. For instance if you add debug code to your program, you'll see that this exclusiveOr area only pops up in the 6th subtraction. I've not yet figured out why, but perhaps if you create an image of the excluxiveOr image you'll see.

Your code with my debug statements (some a bit redundant, sorry):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.List;

public class TestTryMove {
   private static final List<Point> unitCenterPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
   static {
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1720, 120));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1880, 120));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1800, 200));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1720, 280));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(1880, 280));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 120));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 120));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(200, 200));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 280));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 280));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 1720));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 1720));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(200, 1800));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(120, 1880));
      unitCenterPoints.add(new Point(280, 1880));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] xpointsOK = new int[]{1876, 1884, 1918, 1910};// for Move OK
      int[] ypointsOK = new int[]{139, 101, 108, 146};// for Move OK
      Polygon lineOK = new Polygon(xpointsOK, ypointsOK, xpointsOK.length);

      int[] xpointsFAIL = new int[]{1877, 1883, 1917, 1911};// for problem no
                                                            // move
      int[] ypointsFAIL = new int[]{139, 101, 107, 145};// for problem no move
      Polygon lineFAIL = new Polygon(xpointsFAIL, ypointsFAIL,
               xpointsFAIL.length);

      Point endPointCPOK = new Point(1914, 127);// Move OK
      Point endPointCPFAIL = new Point(1914, 126);// problem no move
      // where in both cases it should be move OK
      System.out.println("******TEST for method tryMove()******");
      System.out.println("TEST 1: this will FAIL");
      System.out.println("Result=" + tryMove(endPointCPFAIL, lineFAIL));
      System.out.println("\nTEST 2: this will be OK");
      System.out.println("Result=" + tryMove(endPointCPOK, lineOK));

      System.out.println("******TEST for method tryMove2()******");
      System.out.println("TEST 1: this will be OK");
      System.out.println("Result=" + tryMove2(endPointCPFAIL, lineFAIL));
      System.out.println("\nTEST 2: this will be OK");
      System.out.println("Result=" + tryMove2(endPointCPOK, lineOK));
   }

   private static boolean tryMove(Point endPointCP, Polygon line) {
      Area potentialArea = getArea(endPointCP);
      Area moveLineArea = new Area(line);
      System.out.println(showBounds("moveLine before add", moveLineArea));
      moveLineArea.add(potentialArea);
      System.out.println(showBounds("moveLine after add ", moveLineArea));
      // this area is used for testing if nothing stays on the way of the move
      Area spaceTestArea = new Area(moveLineArea);
      System.out.println(showBounds("spaceTest", spaceTestArea));
      Area xOr = (Area)spaceTestArea.clone();
      xOr.exclusiveOr(moveLineArea);
      System.out.printf("Pre   %s  %s  %s%n", showBounds("STA", spaceTestArea), showBounds("MLA", moveLineArea), 
               showBounds("xOr", xOr)); 

      // the index of the unit making the move in the unitCenterPoints list
      int movingUnitIndexInTheArray = 1;
      // we are subtracting from spaceTestArea all areas of units
      for (int i = 0; i < unitCenterPoints.size(); i++) {
         if (i != movingUnitIndexInTheArray) {
            Point p = unitCenterPoints.get(i);
            Area uArea = getArea(p);
            spaceTestArea.subtract(uArea);
            xOr = (Area)spaceTestArea.clone();
            xOr.exclusiveOr(moveLineArea);
            System.out.printf("i: %02d %s  %s  %s  %s%n", i, 
                     showBounds("STA", spaceTestArea), 
                     showBounds("MLA", moveLineArea), 
                     showBounds("uA", uArea),
                     showBounds("xOr", xOr));         
            // we have intersection then return false, we cannot make this move
            if (spaceTestArea.isEmpty() || !spaceTestArea.equals(moveLineArea)) {
               System.out.println("spaceTestArea.isEmpty()? " + spaceTestArea.isEmpty());
               System.out.println("!spaceTestArea.equals(moveLineArea)? " + !spaceTestArea.equals(moveLineArea));
               System.out.println("moveLineArea bounds: " + moveLineArea.getBounds());
               System.out.println("No move --- a unit is on the way. "
                        + "Conflicting point is=" + p + "; for i=" + i);

               return false;
            }
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Move OK.");
      return true;
   }

   public static String showBounds(String name, Area area) {
      Rectangle rect = area.getBounds();
      StringBuilder resultSB = new StringBuilder();
      Formatter formatter = new Formatter(resultSB);
      formatter.format("%5s [%04d, %04d, %04d, %04d]", name, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);

      return resultSB.toString();
   }

   private static boolean tryMove2(Point endPointCP, Polygon line) {
      Area potentialArea = getArea(endPointCP);
      Area moveLineArea = new Area(line);
      // test if unit can move to the new position
      Area potentialTestArea = new Area(potentialArea);
      // this area is used for testing if nothing stays on the way of the move
      Area spaceTestArea = new Area(moveLineArea);
      // the index of the unit making the move in the unitCenterPoints list
      int movingUnitIndexInTheArray = 1;
      // we are subtracting from spaceTestArea all areas of units
      for (int i = 0; i < unitCenterPoints.size(); i++)
         if (i != movingUnitIndexInTheArray) {
            Point p = unitCenterPoints.get(i);
            Area uArea = getArea(p);
            spaceTestArea.subtract(uArea);
            potentialTestArea.subtract(uArea);
            // we have intersection then return false, we cannot make this move
            if (spaceTestArea.isEmpty() || !spaceTestArea.equals(moveLineArea)
                     || potentialTestArea.isEmpty()
                     || !potentialTestArea.equals(potentialArea)) {
               System.out.println("No move --- a unit is on the way. "
                        + "Conflicting point is=" + p + "; for i=" + i);
               return false;
            }
         }
      System.out.println("Move OK.");
      return true;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the area taken by a unit given the unit's center point.
    * 
    * @param p
    *           the center point of a unit.
    * @return circle area.
    */
   private static Area getArea(Point p) {
      int mod = 40;// this is width and height of a unit
      Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.x - mod / 2, p.y - mod / 2,
               mod, mod);
      return new Area(circle);
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that `Area` implements `equals()` using `xor`. If effect, two areas are equal if they reference the same object or if their overlap is empty. Aliasing? +1, btw.